# Visual Studio 2019 show errors on source files which are building properly

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework, c#, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 Installed and I noticed that I receive build errors in csx files are opened.
However the solution does build successfully but when I got to the file I see a lot of red lines.

An Example could be in places where I have used `Directory` for similar use of `Directory.GetFiles` I get an error under "Directory" saying The name 'Directory' does not exist in current context.

Has anyone come across a similar issue to this ?

Comment: Are you using any other plugins like ReSharper? Have you also tried refreshing the Intellisense cache?

Comment: I am not using Re-Sharper or any other plugins @TimG.

Comment: I also Removed the suo files ... but the issue continued to occur